# Response data undefined

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuejs2

So I'm using Vuelidate to validate my forms. I've tried to create my own validation helper using the plugins docs but It seems to give me "Cannot read property '__isVuelidateAsyncVm' of undefined" error when i try with the axios request. But if i just return true or if I check if the input is equal to a value "a username" it works just as intended.

I've tried to a number of things. My current attempt is: which gives me the error: `Cannot read property '__isVuelidateAsyncVm' of undefined`

```js
export function isUser(value) {
  if(value === "") return true;
  this.$http.get('/api/user/check/'+ value).then((response) => { // this.$http = Axios.get
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data; // returns true or false
  })
}
```

This one doesn't give and error and "works" but always returns as false which forces the error to come up.

```js
export function isUser(value) {
  var isUser;
  this.$http.get('/api/user/check/'+ value).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data) // returns true if value matches a username
    isUser = response.data
  });
  console.log(isUser); // Returns undefined
  return isUser ? true : false
}
```

I've also tried to use the lazy function. `v-model.trim.lazy="$v.username.$model">` but it also didn't change anything and I would prefer it doing it on the fly without .lazy

Comment: Yeah, I have another console log inside and it shows the data. I just can't figure out how to get the data properly and return it.

Comment: `return $this.http.get(...)` will return a promise that you can consume with whatever is calling `isUser()`